# wildly varying performance of cuMemAlloc/cuMemFree

Tags: cuda

In my application cuMemAlloc/cuMemFree seem awfully slow most of the time. However, I found that they are sometimes 10 times faster than usual. The test program below finishes in about 0.4s on two machines, both with cuda 5.5 but one with a compute capability 2.0 card, the other with a 3.5 one.

If the cublas initialization is removed then it takes about 5s. With the cublas initialization in, but allocating a different a different number of bytes such as 4000 it slows down about the same. Needless to say, I'm puzzled by this.

What can be causing this? If it's not a bug in my code, what kind of workaround do I have? The only thing I could think of is preallocating an arena an implementing my own allocator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#define cudaCheck(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

inline void gpuAssert(CUresult code, char *file, int line)
{
    if (code != CUDA_SUCCESS) { 
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %d %s %d\n", code, file, line);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CUcontext   context;
    CUdevice    device;
    int         devCount;

    cudaCheck(cuInit(0));
    cudaCheck(cuDeviceGetCount(&devCount));
    cudaCheck(cuDeviceGet(&device, 0));
    cudaCheck(cuCtxCreate(&context, 0, device));

    cublasStatus_t stat;
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
    if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        printf ("CUBLAS initialization failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
            CUdeviceptr devBufferA;
            cudaCheck(cuMemAlloc(&devBufferA, 8000));
            cudaCheck(cuMemFree(devBufferA));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do the testing with a Release build?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'Release build' means in this context. If it's about the presence of nvcc's -g -G flags, then no, I didn't use them. It was compiled with 'nvcc <file-above> -lcuda -lcublas'.

Answer (score 2):

I took your code and profiled it on a linux 64 bit system with the 319.21 driver and CUDA 5.5 and a non-display compute 3.0 device. My first observation is that the run time is about 0.5s, which seems much faster then you are reporting. If I analyse the nvprof output, I get these histograms:

```
          cuMemFree               
    Time (us)       Frequency     
 3.65190000e+00   2.96670000e+04
 4.59380000e+00   2.76000000e+02 
 5.53570000e+00   3.20000000e+01
 6.47760000e+00   1.00000000e+00
 7.41950000e+00   1.00000000e+00
 8.36140000e+00   6.00000000e+00
 9.30330000e+00   0.00000000e+00
 1.02452000e+01   1.00000000e+00
 1.11871000e+01   2.00000000e+00
 1.21290000e+01   1.40000000e+01

          cuMemAlloc               
    Time (us)       Frequency     
 3.53840000e+00   2.98690000e+04
 4.50580000e+00   8.60000000e+01
 5.47320000e+00   2.00000000e+01
 6.44060000e+00   0.00000000e+00 
 7.40800000e+00   0.00000000e+00
 8.37540000e+00   6.00000000e+00 
 9.34280000e+00   0.00000000e+00
 1.03102000e+01   0.00000000e+00
 1.12776000e+01   1.20000000e+01
 1.22450000e+01   5.00000000e+00
```

which tells me that 99.6% of `cuMemAlloc` calls take less than 3.5384 microseconds, and 98.9% of `cuMemFree` calls take less than 3.6519 microseconds. No free or allocate operation took more than 12.25 microseconds.

So my conclusions based on these results are

1. Both `cuMemfree` and `cuMemAlloc` are *extremely* fast, with every one of the 60000 total calls to those APIs in your example taking less than 12.25 microseconds
2. The median call time for both APIs is 2.7 microseconds, with a standard deviation of 0.25 microseconds, suggesting that there is very little variability in the API latency as well
3. Very occasionally (about 0.01% of the time), both APIs can be around six times slower than this median. This is probably due to operating system level resource contention
4. Every single one of the above points completely contradicts every assertion you have made in your question.

Given how different your results apparently are, I can only guess that you are running on a known high latency platform like WDDM Windows, and that driver batching and WDDM subsystem latency are completely dominating the performance of the code. In that case, it would seem that the simplest workaround is change platforms.....

Comment: Strange. Both results were produced with cuda 5.5, driver version 319.76, running on a Debian Testing installation with Linux 3.12, up-to-date as of a couple of days ago. Neither system has X running. The measurements you posted match what the test program produces here. Commenting out the 7 lines of cublas init makes cuMemAlloc take ~67ms and cuMemFree ~47.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for doing this. Were you able to reproduce the performance difference related to initializing cublas?

Comment: Did you use a release build?

Comment: @RogerDahl: Yes, this is a release build, and no I didn't touch the code. It was a pretty manual process to get 60,000+ lines of nvprof output into python so I could analyse it, and once was more than enough.

Comment: @talonmies: I understand. No need for nvprof though for a quick check: just 'time' how long it takes to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The CUDA memory manager is known to be slow. I've seen mention that it is "two orders of magnitude" slower than host `malloc()` and `free()`. This information may be dated, but there are some graphs here:

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~mwb7w/cuda_support/memory_management_overhead.html

I think this is because the CUDA memory manager is optimized for handling a small number of memory allocations at the cost of slowing down when there is a large number of allocations. And that this is because, in general, it is not efficient to handle many small buffers in a kernel.

There are two main issues with dealing with many buffers in a kernel:

1) It implies passing a table of pointers to the kernel. If there is a pointer for each thread, you incur an initial cost of loading the pointer from a table in global memory, before you can start working with the memory. Following a series of pointers is sometimes called "pointer chasing" and it is especially expensive on a GPU because memory accesses is relatively more expensive.

2) More importantly, a pointer for each thread implies a non-coalesced memory access pattern. On current architectures, if each thread in a warp loads a 32-bit value from global memory that is more than 128 bytes away from the others, 32 memory transaction are required for serving the warp. Each transaction will load 128 bytes and then discard 124 bytes. If all threads in a warp load values from the same natively aligned 128 byte area, all the loads are served by a single memory transaction. So, in a memory bound kernel, memory throughput may be only 1/32 of potential.

The most efficient way to handle memory with CUDA is often to allocate a few large chunks and index into them in the kernel.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's 10 times faster sometimes. Also, while in this contrived example there were indeed lots of allocations, in the production code there are only 400 allocations of arrays of 1210 floats per one epoch of neural network training. If I reuse the same array, then one epoch takes 3s, else it takes about 5s.